# Anaconda Prompt returns errore

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create an environment using the anaconda prompt but I keep on running into this error:

```
(base) C:\Users\lebogang.molapo>conda create --name tensorflow_env
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 122, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\notices\core.py", line 121, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 41, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 264, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 143, in solve_for_transaction
        self._notify_conda_outdated(link_precs)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1011, in _notify_conda_outdated
        SubdirData.query_all(conda_newer_spec, self.channels, self.subdirs,
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 169, in query_all
        result = tuple(chain.from_iterable(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 621, in result_iterator
        yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop())
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 319, in _result_or_cancel
        return fut.result(timeout)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 451, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 158, in subdir_query
        return tuple(
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 174, in query
        self.load()
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 264, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 315, in _load
        cache.load_state()  # XXX should this succeed even if FileNotFound?
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\repodata\__init__.py", line 570, in load_state
        self.load(state_only=True)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\repodata\__init__.py", line 528, in load
        state = json.loads(state_file.read())
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

`$ C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create --name tensorflow_env`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\c
                          onda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\
                          conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\lebogang.molapo
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                     PATH=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3;C:\Users\lebogang.mol
                          apo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\mingw-
                          w64\bin;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\usr\b
                          in;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Use
                          rs\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\lebogang.m
                          olapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Loc
                          al\anaconda3\condabin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System
                          32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32
                          \OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program
                          Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program
                          Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
                          SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\160\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data
                          Studio\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\Ap
                          pData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppDat
                          a\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\.dotnet\too
                          ls;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\App
                          Data\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
                          ules\@angular\cli\bin;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\Programs\
                          Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\Microsoft
                          \WindowsApps;.;C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-
                          posh\bin
         POSH_THEMES_PATH=C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\.condarc
          conda version : 23.3.1
    conda-build version : 3.24.0
         python version : 3.10.9.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=12.0=0
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\lebogang.molapo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/23.3.1 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.10.9 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22621
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]: y
Upload successful.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true


(base) C:\Users\lebogang.molapo>
```

I also get an error when I try to use the Anaconda Navigator

What might be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?